# compile Qt project without installing qt

Tags: qt, compilation, project

I have created a Qt 5 project in Qt Creator.

I want to open and compile this project with Visual Studio 2012 on a computer that doesn't have anything about Qt installed. How can I make the qt libraries follow with my project ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: You do not need to install Qt to build it and to use it with visual studio I do that all the time for the last 5 years or so.. However I generate my visual studio projects with cmake. With that said it would be helpful to understand what your purpose for not installing Qt.

Comment: Do you want them to be able to develop the project, or just compile it?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Visual Studio plugin enabling Qt projects to be build inside Visual Studio IDE as for example this one :

- Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.2 for Qt5
  (supports versions 2008, 2010 and 2012, does not work with the Express edition)
  [Qt Project other downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-other)

With this Add-in and a Qt SDK version for Visual Studio you don't need to install or build with the Qt Creator IDE.
But as **drescherjm** said the installation of a minimal Qt SDK is further a necessary dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cmake to resolve dependencies to the qt dll files. For example put dynamic libraries in a `include-qt5` folder and include the directory in your CMakeLists as follows,

```
include_directories ("/include-qt5")
```

To run your program, you need to copy appropriate dll files next to to your executable (you can use windeployqt to do so).
Note! To use qt classes in your code use relative path to the corresponding header files such as `#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>` and so on. You may need to add the following directives in your code to specify the library that you want the linker to search for,

```
#if defined(NDEBUG)
    #pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Widgets.lib")
#else
    #pragma comment(lib, "Qt5Widgetsd.lib")
#endif
```